# How to integrate Jira cloud with with Gitlab behind VPN

Tags: gitlab, jira, vpn

Our Gitlab is hosted on server and accessed through VPN. We would like to connect it with Jira (cloud). How would it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

You'd normally either need to utilize a proxy for access or ensure your network allows for a direct connection between Jira cloud and your GitLab server. Basically, they need some way to communicate with one another, which will mean creating some method in your network that allows for that.